# General question about Ruby singleton class

Tags: ruby, singleton

```
module MyModule 
  def my_method; 'hello'; end
end

class MyClass 
  class << self
    include MyModule
  end 
end

MyClass.my_method   # => "hello
```

I'm unsure why "include MyModule" needs to be in the singleton class in order to be called using just MyClass.

Why can't I go:

```
X = MyClass.new
X.my_method
```

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question to use the term `singleton class` as it is the official name. Indeed, Ruby 1.9.2 introduces `Object#singleton_class`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`include ModuleName` adds the methods from the module as **instance** methods to the including class.

So if you write

```
class MyClass
  include MyModule
end
```

then `my_method` becomes an instance method on `MyClass` e.g.

```
m = MyClass.new
m.my_method # => "hello"
```

When you include the module inside the singleton class the methods are still being added as instance methods but to the instance of the class `Class` for your class. Therefore they appear as class methods on `MyClass`.

EDIT (Jörg W Mittag): However, you should never do that, since `including` in the singleton class is the same as `extending` the original object, which is preferred. So, this:

```
class MyClass
  class << self
    include MyModule
  end
end
```

is the same as this:

```
class MyClass
  extend MyModule
end
```

You should always use the latter form.

More generally, this:

```
foo = Object.new
class << foo
  include MyModule
end
```

is the same as this:

```
foo = Object.new
foo.extend MyModule
```

EDIT (MAL): If you want to have you method both as an instance method and a method, you can simply define your method as above, and either `extend self` which will bring all instance methods accessible to the module object itself, or alternatively use `module_function :my_method`.

Comment: Your question already covers all the bases, so I added my remarks as an edit instead of a separate answer.

Comment: @Jörg Thanks for doing this - I've always used `extend` myself as well so hadn't really thought about `including` in the singleton class until Dex's question.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the answer to use the term `singleton class` as it is the official name. Indeed, Ruby 1.9.2 introduces `Object#singleton_class`

Comment: I copied Jörg and edited your answer to mention `module_function` too.